# PHP check trait exists before use it

Tags: php

```
class Bar {

     //use Foo;
     if ( trait_exists('foo') ) { use \Foo; }

     public function .......
}
```

I need to check trait exists before "use" it, but i got error.
Is anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only define the class if the trait exists:

```
if (trait_exists('Foo')) {
    class Bar {
        use \Foo;
    }
} else {
    // define alternative Bar class or throw error
}
```

Comment: Bar class still got some other works need to do, it must define

Comment: You cannot do that due to the way PHP defines classes. You could dynamically create a class at runtime: `if (trait_exists('Foo')) { $bar = new class { use \Foo; /* ... */ }; }`. You probably should restructure your code. Traits are probably not the solution to your issue.